# How to use form rules programatically to validate data outside a form

Tags: emails, validation

I've created a component where an admin can bulk upload users and I want to validate the email addresses before creating those users.

The XML definition of the form for creating or modifying a user (`administrator/components/com_users/models/forms/user.xml`), has the attribute `validate=email` on the email field. This means that Joomla will use its `Joomla\CMS\Form\Rule\EmailRule` class to validate any input from the email form field.

I'd like to leverage the `Joomla\CMS\Form\Rule\EmailRule` class for validating the email addresses which are uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to use the `Joomla\CMS\Form\Rule\EmailRule` directly within code. Just instantiate it and then call its `test` method. The `test` method requires two arguments, a SimpleXMLElement defining the field tag the value to be tested. To validate a bunch of uploaded email addresses, you would use the code

```
$emails; //an array of email addresses
$email_validator = new \Joomla\CMS\Form\Rule\EmailRule();
$field_element = simplexml_load_string('<field name="email" type="email" validate="email" />');
foreach( $emails as $email ) {
    if( !$email_validator->test($field_element, $email) ) {
        //deal with failed email validation
    }
}
```

Reviewing the `Joomla\CMS\Form\Rule\EmailRule` class, the SimpleXMLElement only looks for the attributes 'required', 'multiple', 'tld' and 'unique', so if you don't require these, you can actually just use `simplexml_load_string('<field/>)`;

Using the field element definition, you can easily modify the rule's behaviour. For example, if you want to use the `Joomla\CMS\Form\Rules\PasswordRule` to validate passwords, then you can adjust the SimpleXMLElement string to require a minimum total length or number of symbols. The code would look like:

```
$field_element = simplexml_load_string('<field minimum_length="15" minimum_symbols="3" />');
```